# importing Window from kivy.core.window opens a second Kivy window that crashes

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to import from kivy.core.window import Window in order to enable texture support to display an image from a numpy array (see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/2Hvarxhz6lU).

However, when I run the import, Kivy attempts to open another window which is blank and unresponsive. When I remove the import statement, the app launches as normal.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to import Window to allow Texture support without this behaviour?

Thanks,

Oliver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is highly expected because Kivy is built on this importing behavior. On a simple `Window` import e.g. in a console:

```
>>> from kivy.core.window import Window
```

a blank OpenGL window is created and it waits for further instructions such as first drawing and other initialization stuff.

Let's look at the code from the mailing list:

```
class MainConsole():
    def build(self):
        texture = Texture.create()  # no window, boom
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()  # except other stuff also creates a window
```

To make this actually work you will have to create the texture ***after*** the `Window` is created i.e. this:

```
class MainConsole():
    def build(self):
        from kivy.core.window import Window
        texture = Texture.create()  # window, no boom
```

The struggle might happen if you try to do that in a `Thread`(not sure) or with `multiprocessing`(most likely) if you try to do something like:

```
def blob():
    from kivy.core.window import Window
    texture = Texture.create()
```

if you run this function in a separate process, the separate process won't have the same `Window`, therefore it creates a new one with the `Window` import and here you are.

To fix it you can do two things:

- use [`Config`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.config.html) and move the `Window` somewhere out of the viewing area with `top` and `left`
- create and assemble the texture within the main `Window`

Comment: Thanks for the insights! Just to mention, that the problem also arises (and is a real problem) when you have production test on a headless system (e.g. Jenkins/GitHub actions). Even if you pytest.mark the tests as not to be executed, the order of imports might lead to an import statement being executed and then crashing the test.